# Derby Select over subquery not working

Tags: sql, database, select, subquery, derby

Does Derby not allow you to select over the returned relation of another query?

For example, this query works fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users, stats 
WHERE users.uid = stats.uid;
```

but this query returns an error:

```
SELECT username, hits 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM users, stats 
  WHERE users.uid = stats.uid
);
```

The error reads:

```
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 83.
SQLState:  42X01
ErrorCode: 30000
```

I am used to Oracle where this works fine.

The above query is just an example, I know I can select username, hits originally without the need for a nested query.

Comment: Not sure if derby requires to have the inline query use table alias but you may want to try `SELECT username, hits FROM (SELECT * FROM users, stats WHERE users.uid = stats.uid) B;`  Most RDBMS require that you alias inline queries.

Comment: Hi just tried that and it works, except you must use the AS keyword to alias. Thanks alot

Comment: Note: on your last question, I was not the down-voter. I didn't think that it was a bad question, just a premature one. The reason that you couldn't find on Google a solution is likely because you were looking for a solution to the whole thing, and you won't find that. You still need to divide your steps, and doing this does not require Swing knowledge. Then when you try to solve each small step, if you fail that, you **will** be able to find Google or StackOverflow solutions, or failing that, post a better more specific question. Much luck!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Cool, I think that is a fair point. I just figured out a way to do it, using a jTextPane and setCaretPosition, just starting a thread that animates it by looping and updating the caret postion then delaying during each cycle. Until I reach the end of the text, then setCaret to the top. I haven't tried it out, but I imagine it might work. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by xQbert above, Derby requires you to alias tables in an inline query.

The solution to the question is to do this:

```
SELECT username, hits 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM users, stats 
  WHERE users.uid = stats.uid
) AS tmp;
```

Thanks for the help xQbert

Comment: I think it is a bug. Does derby have a plan for fix it?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's a bug. I think maybe its just the way their SQL dialect works. but im not an expert on this